# Java String.replaceAll not replacing concurrent repeated sequences

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I'm attempting to use String.replaceAll to chop some whitespace out of a string.  However, when multiple concurrent instances of the regex pattern appear in the string, only every 2nd one is replaced.

Very simple example:

```
String theString = "foo x x x x x bar";        
String trimmed = theString.replaceAll("x\\s*x", "xx");        
System.out.println(theString);
System.out.println(trimmed);
```

What I want to see:

```
foo x x x x x bar
foo xxxxx bar
```

What I see:

```
foo x x x x x bar
foo xx xx x bar
```

It seems that replaceAll doesn't consider the replacement text as a candidate for being itself replaced, and instead skips merrily onwards.

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: *"It seems that replaceAll doesn't consider the replacement text as a candidate for being itself replaced, and instead skips merrily onwards."* Correct, that would be **very** unusual behavior for any string replacement method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you match the `x` after the space; as such, after your first match, you match:

```
foo x x x x x bar
       ^
       |---- HERE
```

You don't want to swallow it; you have to use a lookahead:

```
.replaceAll("x\\s+(?=x)", "x");
```

You could even go with both a lookahead and a lookbehind:

```
.replaceAll("(?<=x)\\s+(?=x)", "");
```

(note that the `*` quantifier has been replaced with `+`; it allows not to match where there are no space characters, in which case you don't want to replace anyway)

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for, and clearly explained. Many thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it suits you ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
theString.replaceAll("(?<=x)\\s+(?=x)", "");
```